# Can not resolve symbol "newBuilder" protobuf

Tags: java, intellij-idea, protocol-buffers

I wanted to test how protobuf works and implement it into my sample project. Basicly I have just compiled .proto to .java and copied this java class to my projects source. But whenever I try to reach inner methods of this class the IDE (Intellij) just says that it can not be resolved and marks it red. Only thought I can think of that this class has to be imported or something instead of just simply moved to the project.

So is there some way to import classes to existing project or there might be other problems? By the way, .proto is valid and compiler successfully produces .java.

Comment: Do you use (the idea equivalent of) maven project nature/plugin or do you use mvn eclipse:eclipse and then import it at an existing project?

Answer (score -2):

More of a guess, I am new to protobuf myself and it's tricky.

Is `com.google.protobuf...` or anything on the classpath too? It sounds like you may have included only the generated files.

Comment: This should be a comment, seeing how it doesn't answer the question

Comment: com.google.protobuf, com.googlecode.protobuf-java-format - those two I have added as a dependencies to projects pom and imported.

Comment: @Vince I am always back and forth on making things like this an answer or a comment. The comment box does say "Avoid answering questions in comments." In my opinion I tried to answer it rather than just seeking clarification, so I put it as an answer.

Comment: @CaptainMan Trust me, it's a lot better to answer a question in a comment than comment as an answer. Yes, it's good to avoid answering questions in the comment section **if you are 100% sure about the answer**. Otherwise, if you aren't sure about something, such as "*Is ... on the classpath?*", leave a comment so the OP can update his question. You'd be surprised how many times I've been downvoted for such things when I first joined the site..